# How to make row have 4 products instead of 3 on Magento categories page

Tags: php, magento, layout, categories, product

I'm new to magento.

I've been trying to change from a 3 products per row layout to a 4 products per row layout.

I've been searching but I can't find any solution.

Here's my closest approach:
I changed "app/design/frontend/default/mytemplate/template/catalog/product/list.phtml" and set
'$_columnCount=4'.

The problem is that I still receive 9 products each time, so  I get 2 rows with 4 products each but the last one only has 1 product.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How many Products per Page on Grid you want ?

Comment: 12 products = 3 rows * 4 products

Answer (score 0):

You can determine the column count through layout/catalog.xml

Find the line that looks like this:

```
<action method="setColumnCount"><columns>4</columns></action>
```

Change the value of 4 to 3.

Answer (score 0):

Go to System > Configuration > Catalog > Frontend

Set `Products per Page on Grid Allowed Values = 12,18,30`

Set `Products per Page on Grid Default Value = 12`

Save

Comment: It didn't work either. My template is loading 9 products each time and I can't find a '9' anywhere.

Comment: Do you have multiple stores ? Also in your catalog/product/list.phtml print value of `$_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount();`

Comment: No. And '$this->getColumnCount();' prints 3.

Comment: Try to set '$_columnCount=4' and then print its value

Comment: The problem is that "$this->getLoadedProductCollection();" is returning 9 products instead of 12.

Comment: After changing the values from admin, in your list.phtml print your collection query `$yourCollection->printlogquery->(true);` and check the LIMIT at the end of your query.

Comment: The limit is 9. How can I change it to 12?

Answer (score 0):

I was working on a custom theme, for mobile view. my requirement was to show two products in a row and by default it was four.
 I just widened the li product-item and this worked for me.

```
>ol.product-items{
    >li.product-item{
        border:@border-1;
        width: 45%;
    }
}
```

- Changing the width can also affect product listing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set column count for both anchor and non-anchor layout handle in the catalog.xml.

Answer (score -1):

try following this. it worked.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/12899/display-more-items-per-row-in-products-page

and also make sure that your list.phtml layout is coded accordingly.